# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI error?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a spring boot project.
It has three files.
Appconfig.java

```
package config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
(basePackages = {"controller"})
public class AppConfig {
}
```

ServletInitilizer.java

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[0];
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("hi")
    @ResponseBody
    public String hi() {
    return "Hello, world.";
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, it has error "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringC1_01/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'".
Is this because server didn't find the controller or other reason? Thx.

Comment: Try add a @controller annotation for your HelloController

Comment: @UdonN00dle. Thx.I tried and it has new error. "Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
 * Activation of http://localhost:8080/SpringC1_01/hi resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
  + Exception reading manifest from http://localhost:8080/SpringC1_01/hi: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
  + Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: Ok, new error is good haha. I haven't seen this error, perhaps try this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782798/manifest-may-not-be-valid-or-the-file-could-not-be-opened

Answer (score 0):

Yes. i suspect two issues in the code.

1. @SpringBootApplication annotation is missing in  AppConfig.
2. @RestController annotation is missing in HelloController.

Answer (score 0):

Most of all you are missing a couple of things here.

1. Main class which contains **public static void main** and this class should be annotated with @SpringBootApplication
2. HelloController should be annotated with @RestController
3. At method level it should definitely point to some HTTP method in your case perhaprs it is Get mapping, so add @GetMapping annotation arround the method.
4. Move RequestMapping annotation from method level and add it to HelloController class.